# We were unable to submit your request. Please try again! in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, forms, submission

I have created the custom page and tried submitting form.

I am getting below error "We were unable to submit your request. Please try again!".

Below is code for contoller

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;     
 class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $helperData;
 protected $_fieldsetConfig;
 protected $_customerSession; 
 protected $customerFactory;
 protected $_objectManager;
 protected $_customer; 
 protected $_messageManager;
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Inkind\Customer\Helper\Data $helperData,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config $fieldsetConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager     

) {
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    $this->_fieldsetConfig = $fieldsetConfig;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
    $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager; 
    $this->_customer = $customer; 
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;       

    parent::__construct($context);
}   

  public function execute()
{       
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        //$user = $this->customerFactory->setId(null);
        $user = $this->_customer->setId(null);
        $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create(); 
        $master_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getMasterId();
        $master = $this->_customer->load($master_id); 
        //$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $defaultFields = array();
        $customerAccount = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('customer_account');

        foreach ($customerAccount as $code=>$node) {
            $defaultFields[] = $code;
            if (isset($data[$code])) {
                if ($code == 'email') {
                    $data[$code] = trim($data[$code]);
                }
                $user->setData($code, $data[$code]);
            }
        }

        $customerattr = $this->helperData->getCustomerUserDefinedAttributes();
        foreach ($customerattr as $_customerattr) {
            if (isset($data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]) && (!in_array($_customerattr, $defaultFields))) {
                $user->setData($_customerattr->getAttributeCode(), $data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]);
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->_getSharedFields() as $_att) {
            $user->setData($_att, $master->getData($_att));
        }

        try {
            $user->save();  
            $userId = $user->getId();           

            $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__('User was successfully created.'));
            //$this->sendNewSubUserAccountEmail($user);         
            return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/listuser/');

            } 
    catch (\Exception $e){
             $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e->getMessage());

    $this->_messageManager->addError(__('We were unable to submit
        your request. Please try again!'));
           return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/listuser/');
        }       

     }

 }
```

here is my phtml file code.

```
   <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('inkindcustomer/subuser/createpost') ?>" method="post" id="newuser_form">

<div class="fieldset">
<h2 class="legend"><?php echo 'User Information'; ?></h2>
<ul class="form-list">

    <li>
        <label for="firstname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'First Name'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" title="<?php echo 'First Name'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="24" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="lastname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Last Name'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" title="<?php echo 'Last Name'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry"  maxlength="24" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Email Address'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo 'Email Address'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry validate-email"  maxlength="200" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Phone No.'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo 'Phone No.'; ?>" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="30" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="job_title" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Job Title/Position'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" title="<?php echo 'Job Title/Position'; ?>" class="input-text required-entry"  maxlength="50" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="department"><?php echo 'Department'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="department" id="department" title="<?php echo 'Department'; ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="50" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php 
            $options[] = array('value' => '', 'code'    => 'Please select...');
            $options[] = array('value' => 1, 'code' => 'Account Controller');
            $options[] = array('value' => 2, 'code' => 'Order Authorisation');
        ?>
        <label for="user_level" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Access Level'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="user_level" id="user_level" title="<?php echo 'Access Level'; ?>" class="validate-select required-entry" >
                <?php foreach ($options as $_option): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_option['value']?>"><?php echo $_option['code'] ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php $currency = '£'; ?>
        <label for="order_limit"><?php echo 'Order Value Limit'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="order_limit" id="order_limit" title="<?php echo 'Order Value Limit'; ?>" class="input-text validate-currency validate-number" maxlength="10" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
   <div class="buttons-set form-buttons">         
     <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo 'Save'; ?>">
    <?php echo 'Save'; ?></span></span></button>
      </div>
   <p class="required"><?php echo '* Required Fields'; ?></p>
  </form>
```

I checked all my code is correct, Don't know the reason for this message.
Please anyone suggest me on this.

Comment: Can be the reason if you are trying on localhost.

Comment: can you please upload your file code?

Comment: No, I am not doing in localhost.

Comment: Are the emails working correctly? And default Magento contact form?

Comment: check Magento log files

Comment: @LAW, Yes, default Magento contact form is working..

Comment: Can you also post phtml code, as could be formkey issue. And share logs as suggested by @kunj

Comment: hi, i have posted my phtml code. please have a look.

Comment: Why are you not using Customer Factory? I mean is there any specific reason? Seems it should work using Factory. And if still not working, can you pass the array static once in the save action, and share the logs if you get any?

Comment: I am using customer Factory. I am not getting any errors in log, but getting this unable save request error on frontend

Comment: Where you are asking me to use customer Factory?